# SQL Server : get query of created table in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in a database created by constructor. Is it possible that I can somehow get the SQL query that was used to create this table?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, right click on the table in the MS. "Script table as" -> "Create to" ->New query editor window.